# How to include Zend Framework 2 and modules as external library?

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to include zend application as an external library and use my custom modules outside the normal application MVC.
How to autoload the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and probably cleanest) solution might be to handle your external dependencies via *Composer*. See http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer which describes how to retrieve the ZF2 libraries this way. Composer also manages autoloading, that is, if installed this way, then the ZF2 classes are loadable without any further configuration on your side.